# How to override bootstrip.min.css in Joomla-Template CSS file for width 768-1140px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, responsive-design

I struggle to set website CENTER and RIGHT columns width correctly, but only between a screen width of 768px and 1140px, the following width-override via template.css is not effective at all:

```html
@media (max-width: 1140px) and (min-width: 768px)
{
.row-fluid .span8 {width: 80%;}
}
```

For all other screen widths, the standard settings from bootstrap.min.css work just fine. Override file name is template.css, Joomla 3.5 CMS. See the site here: http://www.alphaseeker.de
Thanks in advance, let me know any further details you may need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add this line to bootstrap.min.css file, and this rule will work fine!

Comment: Oleg, if I set the screen width to 1000px and then in CHROME CSS console apply the above CSS .row-fluid .span8 then it works fine. If I add this CSS to template.css (as override with the @media code), it is not even visible, nor effective.....

Comment: The element I am working in is <div class="fixedheightcol equalize span8 l-on r-on" style="min-height: 6202px;"> which is below #region3

Comment: @Ralph yep, found it.

Comment: Oleg, thank you so much! I tried this already before, but to no effect - perhaps a caching issue. Greetings to Kyiv! Ralph

Comment: @Ralph Thank you so much! I'm really appreciate it!

Comment: You shouldn't add it to the css. You should add it to the appropriate less file and then compile it into the css. You can do this in the tmeplate manager.  Even better propable to add a custom file and include it.